# Are cookies and sessions are depend on each other?

Tags: php, session, cookies, dependencies, relationship

Are cookies and sessions depend on each other in PHP?

Does deleting or clearing either one of them affect the other?

Does by disabling either one of them in the browser affect the other?

P.S. I am newbie.

**Edit**: I was newbie at time of writing question. This question is faced by many newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are totally **independent**...

- Cookies cannot store unlimited value, sessions can
- You cannot store data in a cookie if user browser cookie is disabled where in session you can, because session id can append to URL
- It is better to store data in sessions than to store in cookies because cookies can be tempered
- If you delete cookies, then only those functionalities in your site will be disabled in which you are retrieving these cookies data but you'll be logged in and if you delete session cookie, you'll be logged out.. (1)
- Cookies are stored on client machine where session are stored on your server
- A session is ended if you close you browser while cookies stay there unless they are manually removed by the user or till they are expired

Inshort you've better control over sessions than on cookies

(1) For example if you are setting a cookie name `demo` and you are using a splash screen unless and until the demo is set you'll show a splash screen

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['demo'])) { //Now this will show lightbox always if user has disabled his cookies
   <script>...</script>
}
```

Articles

http://www.klovera.com/php-sessions-vs-cookies/

Reference

[Session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

[Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: Cleared some thoughts. I think cookies store session id. By clearing sessions wont it affect cookies.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk if you delete the session cookie you'll be logged out, but if you delete some other cookie it wont affect session unless and until you use it for some purpose kinda check a set cookie via login, I already explained you, you should read my answer

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are stored on server, while cookies are on client. You can disable only cookies from your browser. Cookies can't affect session at all. In case of disabled cookies session id is passed via URL. If your cookies are enabled and session id is stored in cookie by deleting cookie you will not be able to access your session (It's still on server but you can't access it)

Also session can't affect cookies.

Comment: I think cookies store session id. By clearing sessions wont it affect cookies.

Answer (score 1):

They are not connected, but by default PHP stores the session id within a cookie, The directive [session.use_cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) is defaulted to 1

If cookies are disabled it uses URL. This can be set with [session_use_trans_id.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) (default is disabled)

But if you delete a session cookie on the client, the next request to the server will not be able to find its associated session

Clearing session will not affect the cookies as cookies are attached with the HTTP request from the client to the server. A cookie can be set to expire after x amount of time, after which it is deleted on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are correct, just wanted to add this - If you do not set the timestamp for cookie, then the cookie is dependent on session and it will expire as soon as session ends.