# if sessions are stored in files why are cookies still used to store them?

Tags: php, session, cookies

**CLIENT:**
`start_session()` creates a cookie (by default): `Name: PHPSESSID; Content: 1q2w3e4r5t; Domain: '/'; Expires:...`

**SERVER:**
It also creates a file stored in (my case): `/var/lib/php/sessions`. Call that in there: `sess_1q2w3e4r5t`. (Absolute path: `/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_1q2w3e4r5t`)

So we have **two** physical things that are bonded to the session I just created.

- What is the point of having both?
- Can I just store my session in `/var/lib/php/sessions` regardless of `use_only_cookies` option?
- I have a classic example with a `$_SESSION['counter']` variable. Meaning that, every time I reload the `example.php` page, the `$_SESSION['counter']` increments (`++`) by one. So, on the loop of pressing the `F5` button, lets say I got `55` as the value of `$_SESSION['counter']`. Finally I its that cookie but **not** the `/var/lib...` file. After that deletion **I get a** `56` and the loop continues as normal. This just intrigued me and got me with the question. Are session cookies necessary?
- Is still possible a way in which my site just stores session only in the server and not using cookies?

This is how I deleted the cookie. notice `counter` value is 69.

[image: Deleting the cookie]

Then `F5`:

[image: are cookies necessary?]

Comment: Huh? Without cookies, all your requests will be stateless.

Comment: But.. like I said, after removing the cookie, `$_SESSION['counter']` still kept the same value... correct me if I'm wrong referring it as a kind of request

Comment: Are you possibly mixing up the fact that removing a cookie is not the same as deleting a session or a session variable? You'll have to use `unset($_SESSION['counter'])` in PHP to *lose* its value.

Comment: Well, recently I've read [cookies vs sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253633/cookie-vs-session) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411820/are-cookies-and-sessions-are-depend-on-each-other) . I've realized that one is stored in the server and the other client-side. But, is still possibly a way in which my site just stores session only in the server and not using cookies?

Comment: The cookie that PHP is using for sessions is `PHPSESSID`. `GLOBAL_SESS` must be something you've set somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the
>   so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user
>   side or is propagated in the URL.

- The point of having both session and cookie is the quote above

In short: without cookies, the client would become a strange visitor

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is there so that the client can tell the server which session file is theirs. The cookie value corresponds to the file that's created on the server.

Without it, the server will just create a new session file for the client, and obviously none of the data from the previous request will be there.

I can only imagine that you are not deleting the cookie properly.

Comment: I would tokenize the session file to obtain the session ID: `sess_ + 1q2w3e4r5t`. Thus, not needing a cookie.

Comment: So how do you know in two subsequent requests if a client is the same person? You're just talking about things on the server side. The client needs to tell the server which session is theirs.